C# Entity Framework Core .NET 8 : DbUpdateConcurrencyException on simple NUnit test with no database activity or threads
I am getting a DbUpdateConcurrencyException. It seems to work sometimes as I change code, but fails most of the time, and I have not been able to find a pattern as I change test code.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException : The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

When I have to a SQL Server database, and no other programs accessing the same, and no async in node.
The self contained NUnit function is:

Delete existing records with the given name by

Fetch the records using DbSet.Where with the given name
Execute DbSet.RemoveRange
Execute DbContext.SaveChanges (Fails here)


Create a Database record

Execute DbSet.Add
Execute DbContext.SaveChanges (Ok here)


Refresh the record

Fetch the records using DbSet.Where with the primary keys
(This fetches same record as written, but in a separate C# variable)
Make the modifications on the C# structure
Execute DbContext.SaveChanges (Fails here)



The C# function (simple one)
DbUserView initialView = new DbUserView { 
    userName = 'test', fromUrl = 'http://localhost:5000', 
    eventType = 'quiz', sectionId = 'firstSection', pageId = 'firstPage',
    startTime = DateTime.Now, lastActiveTime = DateTime.Now };
    
[Test]
public void Expt2() 
{
    string? userName = initialView.userName;
    var dbUserViews = exptContext.userViews.Where(
        dbUserView => dbUserView.userName == userName);

    if (dbUserViews.Count() > 0) 
    {
        exptContext.userViews.RemoveRange(dbUserViews);
        exptContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    exptContext.userViews.Add(initialView);
    exptContext.SaveChanges();

    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    DbUserView? _refreshView = exptContext.userViews.Find(
        initialView.userName, initialView.fromUrl, initialView.startTime);

    if (_refreshView == null) 
        Assert.Fail("Db fetch gave null view");
    else 
    {
        DbUserView refreshView = (DbUserView)_refreshView;
        refreshView.lastActiveTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

        exptContext.userViews.Update(refreshView);
        exptContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var change = exptContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView;
        exptContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

The database record (nothing fancy)
[Table("user_views")]
[PrimaryKey(nameof(userName), nameof(fromUrl), nameof(startTime))]
public class DbUserView 
{
    [Column("user_name")]
    public string userName { get; set; }

    [Column("from_url")]
    public string fromUrl { get; set;}

    [Column("event_type")]
    public string eventType { get; set;}

    [Column("frame_id")]
    public string frameId { get; set;}

    [Column("sub_frame_id")]
    public string subFrameId { get; set;}

    [Column("start_time")]
    public DateTime startTime  { get; set; }

    [Column("last_active_time")]
    public DateTime lastActiveTime { get; set; }
}

And the context is (nothing fancy)
public class ExptContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<DbUserView> userViews { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string? connStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLCONNSTR_DbConn");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connStr);
    }

    public static ExptContext dbContext = new ExptContext();
}

I also tried to print the changes using code below, but debug log was straightforward (since I have only one record)
private void showChanges() 
{
    exptContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var changes = exptContext.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(changes);
}

Parts of the code work sometimes, and it is pretty random.
Specific questions (in addition to your thoughts)
Is there something basic I am missing?

Try do not call Update, it is not needed.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Do you believe that calling it so is a problem?
Actually, the Add and Update are supposed to be within a rest service, and modelled in a separate insert and update call. I faced some concurrency issues between server and unit-test client. That is why I tried to get it all into the same program.
The odd thing is the first Remove itself faced a problem. I am not able to explain this at all.

Try before "refresh", to call exptContext.ChangeTracker.Clear(), it should reset context. Also remove Update.

Yes, that worked. The add and refresh in the same function worked together.
I still need to check the delete at the top.
Interesting that none of the existing literature guides this, even though this is obvious when mentioned. (I guess that is what SOF is for)

@mark_s Thanks for the edits. I did not realize "standard markdown" could be used for this.

The following rules/facts, as given by @SvyatoslavDanyliv, not clearly documented elsewhere.

When doing UnitTests through VSCode, the context seems to be preserved across multiple test-runs. So, creating the DbContext object inside the Test, instead of a global DbContext object helps

When using the same Context object after a DbContext.SaveChanges, it simplifies code to Clear the ChangeTracker. This has been added to the code.

When fetching an object and updating the object, there is no need to call DbSet.Update(). The DbContext.saveChanges itself takes care of it. In fact, DbSet.Update() actually causes a DbUpdateConcurrencyException

The three sections are separate, and the write of one section was not observed in the read of the other section. So, a TransactionScope was placed inside the DbContext. This also helped when the first section was in a UnitTest, and the other two sections were part of individual rest calls.


To summarize, it looks like this may be a good design pattern. But will have to keep in observation for a little while longer.
The solution


Only the test function changed

    public void AllSteps() {

        // Add this envelope
        using(ExptContext exptContext = new ExptContext()) 
        using(TransactionScope xaction = new TransactionScope())
        {

            var dbUserViews = exptContext.userViews.Where(
                dbUserView => dbUserView.userName == userName);
            if (dbUserViews.Count() > 0) {
                exptContext.userViews.RemoveRange(dbUserViews);
                exptContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            xaction.Complete();
        }

        DbUserView initialView = getInitialView();

        using(ExptContext exptContext = new ExptContext()) 
        using(TransactionScope xaction = new TransactionScope())
        {

            exptContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();
            exptContext.userViews.Add(initialView);
            exptContext.SaveChanges(false);
            xaction.Complete();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine(initialView.startTime);

        using(ExptContext exptContext = new ExptContext()) 
        using(TransactionScope xaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            exptContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();

            DbUserView? refreshView =  exptContext.userViews.First(
                dbUserView =>
                    ( dbUserView.userName == initialView.userName ) && 
                    ( dbUserView.fromUrl == initialView.fromUrl ) &&
                    dbUserView.startTime.Equals(initialView.startTime) 
            );
            if (refreshView == null) Assert.Fail("refreshView is null");
            refreshView.lastActiveTime = GetCurrentDateTime();
            exptContext.SaveChanges();
            xaction.Complete();
        }           
    }


FYI A DbContext is a UnitOfWork and its lifetime is very short. Create it, do the work (Create, Read, Update, Delete) and then dispose it.

writing all this code to mitigate these issues that are showing up during unit testing is really a sign that you need to look at the underlying code.  None of this should be needed for a simple unit test.
